# laravel update multiple request arrays

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm really struggling with this update method, any help will be heartfully appreciated.

I'm send multiple car number plates, that is assocaited with the resident, i can successfully store and retrive it, now i want to update it.

when I return or dd on `$request->cars`, it gives me this array.

```
array:2 [
0 => array:5 [
"id" => 10
"user_id" => 33
"car_number_plate" => "12f3456"
"created_at" => null
"updated_at" => null
]

1 => array:5 [
"id" => 11
"user_id" => 33
"car_number_plate" => "abc -123"
"created_at" => null
"updated_at" => null
]   
]
```

Here I find the accociated id, that needs to be updated

```
$userId = ResidentCar::where('user_id', $resident->id)->pluck('id')
->toArray();
```

it return this array.

```
array:2 [
0 => 10
1 => 11
]
```

Here i loop through the array and trying to update it.

```
$input = $request-cars;

foreach ($input as $row)
{
$cars[] = [
    'user_id' => $resident->id,
    'car_number_plate' => $row['car_number_plate'],
];
}

ResidentCar::whereIn('id', $userId)->update(array($cars));
```

it gives this error of,  `Array to string conversion.`

and if do it with

```
ResidentCar::whereIn('id', $userId)->update($cars);
```

it gives this error.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `resident_cars` set `0` = 33,
```

Can anyone here please help on how to solve it, or any better approach thin this.

Comment: try put `array cars` outside `foreach`

Comment: have you done ?? and you can't update multiple array like this, you need to put update function insight for-each  tried ??

Comment: you are using wrong the following line `ResidentCar::whereIn('id', $userId)->update($cars);` this is when you want to update multiples rows with the same data, if you want to update multiple rows with different data you need to do multiples updates.

Comment: @AgeValed, thank you, can you please give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Like I say in a comment, you need to do one update per row.

If the row you want to update is the `$resident->id` and the data you want to update is the `$row['car_number_plate']` you need to do the following:

```
$input = $request-cars;
foreach ($input as $row) {
  $data = [
    'car_number_plate' => $row['car_number_plate'],
  ];
  ResidentCar::where('id',$resident->id)->update($data);
}
```

Let me know if works

Comment: Call to a member function update() on null.

is this the correct way?
ResidentCar::find($resident->id)->update($data);

Comment: Edited, I replaced find with where, assuming `id`